# What is the difference between View and Redirection in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, view, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I understand that this question might sound stupid to a few but I am new to Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.

Suppose I am on `page1.html` currently. The user clicks on some button which generates a POST/GET request to my controller `MyController.java` that maps this request to some function using `@RequestMapping`.

After I am done processing the request I return a view name like `return "page2"` from my controller.

Contents of the `page1.html` **change** but the **url still remains the same** like `http://localhost:8080/page1` instead of changing to `http://localhost:8080/page2`

I know that in order to go to a different page I have to use `redirection` but why is this not possible with **view**?

Could someone explain me why does this happen and when should I use redirection or when should I use view?

**EDIT 1:**

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping (value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="action=ADD")
{
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute UserDto userDto) {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            if(userDto.getId() != null) {   
                throw new UserExists();
            }
            user.setName(userDto.getName());
            user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
            System.err.println("Request Recieved");
            userDao.save(user);
            return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error Saving User");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "failure";
        }
    }
```

Here is my view

```
<form id="manipulate-data-form"  th:object="${userobj}" method="post" th:action="@{/edit}">
        <table id="manipulate" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" th:if="${userobj != null}" th:field="*{id}" ></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>NAME</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" th:if="${userobj != null}" th:field="*{name}" ></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EMAIL</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" th:if="${userobj != null}" th:field="*{email}" ></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="action" value="ADD" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ></input></td>
                <td>
                    <input name="action" value="DELETE" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" ></input> 
                    <input style="margin-left: 30px" name="action" value="UPDATE" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

So basically clicking the button it invokes the saveUser() Controller and then when I return the **failure** or **success** view the URL remains the same but the contents of the the page change corresponding to success or failure.

Comment: any update on your question?

Comment: @Patrick sorry couldn't reply earlier. I was out for a while. But i have added the code in EDIT 1.

Comment: Look up my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to answer some of your questions:

> The contents of the page1.html change but the url still remains the
>   same like http://localhost:8080/page1 instead of changing to
>   http://localhost:8080/page2

You are hitting an URL like `http://localhost:8080/page1`. `/page1` does not mean to show your view with the name `page1.html`. Its more the Url for your `@RequesteMapping` annotation and which method should be executed for this request.

**For example:**

Your are hitting the Url:

`http://localhost:8080/page1` and your mapping is: `@RequestMapping("/page1")` and you want return `page1.html`. So your view is: `return "page1";`

Now you see the content of your `page1.html`. Your provided button should now have a link to `http://localhost:8080/page2` and your Controller should have a mapping to it `@RequestMapping("/page2")`. In this method you can return your `return "page2"` and your Url will change to `http://localhost:8080/page2`.

And if the link of the button does have **another** value instead of `http://localhost:8080/page2` but you want to show this particular URL of `/page2` you need a redirection: `return "redirect:/page2"` in the method of the particular `@RequestMapping("/anyOtherMapping")`.

---

> Could someone explain me why does this happen and when should I use redirection or when should I use view?

I am not 100% sure if this is correct but I think its just a rule why there is view and redirection. If you want to stand on the particular URL and want to show the view which was build for that, just do it. If you dont want to show the same URL or want to switch to another page, just use redirection.

A redirection also calls a controller again which is correct mapped to your redirections URL and return a view.

Some examples for using redirection are the follows:

- after a successful login you can redirect to an users home page.
- after saving an item (REST approach) you can redirect to the specific id for this item `/item/1` and return a view which includes informations of that item.

---

Answer for your edit question:

Try to use `redirection` for changing url.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="action=ADD")
{
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute UserDto userDto) {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            if(userDto.getId() != null) {   
                throw new UserExists();
            }
            user.setName(userDto.getName());
            user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
            System.err.println("Request Recieved");
            userDao.save(user);
            return "redirect:/success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error Saving User");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/failure";
        }
    }

@RequestMapping("/success")
public String successPage(){
    return "success";
}

@RequestMapping("/failure")
public String failurePage(){
    return "failure";
}
```

This should change the URL because you will make a redirection from your `/edit` to `/failure` or `/success` page. You can also give parameters within your redirection if you want.

Comment: "And you show /page1 instead of /page2 because you **want** to show /page1 by returning a view" - I am not sure I understand this line of yours. Could you elaborate this?

Comment: @amitection added some content. Hope its more clear now.

Comment: now i see what you are trying to say. But like you said ** "In this method you can return your return "page2" and your Url will change to http://localhost:8080/page2"** - this does not happen. On clicking the button the URL remains the same i.e **http://localhost:8080/page1** but the contents of the page1 is replaced by page2.

Comment: @amitection can you provide you controller class and the html part of your button please. I think this would help. :)